# Force dom depending on a Binding to rerender

Tags: scala.js, binding.scala

How can I force dom-elements depending on a binding (like the value-attribute of an input-element) to rerender even if the value of the binding has not changed.

Binding itself does not expose such a method and I was not able to use one of the other classes like Map in my code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting! Some one just asked a reverse question to avoid re-rendering a DOM element at [Toomany DOM updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48024292/toomany-dom-updates) .

So, the answer to your question is reverse committing [the PR](https://github.com/ccamel/playground-binding.scala/pull/1/) mentioned in the other question.

Comment: Thank you very much for your soon answer, but I do not get it: My problem is, that the value of my binding does not change, but I want other bindings (especially the dom-binding) depending on this one to "believe" it did. Do you suggest I should introduce a dummy-binding, that I change when I want the rerendering to occur? Using a bind-call as in the PR would also rerender the whole element (and it's children), but all I want is to rerender the value-attribute...

Comment: Dummy-binding is an obvious workaround. However if you want to perform some side-effects that are not triggered by data changing, why not simply call the side-effectful function directly?

Comment: Because the only thing I want to do is to rerender the value-attribute in the dom which is bound to my binding...