# Toomany DOM updates

Tags: scala, performance, dom, scala.js, binding.scala

The link [https://ccamel.github.io/playground-binding.scala/index.html#playground-binding.scala/home]
has few demos of binding.scala
I have used DomListner extension in chrome to understand the dom events.
I found for each interaction there are hundreds of DOM events fired. 
For example one click on calculator button results in 114 events.

1. It this a performance issue ?
2. Does binding.scala library need performance improvements ?
3. Does the code written using binding.scala need optimization ?

[image: DomListener ScreenShot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the expected behavior, because the DEMO that you mentioned recreated anchor elements, explicitly.

According to the [Scaladoc for `bind` method](https://javadoc.io/page/com.thoughtworks.binding/binding_2.12/latest/com/thoughtworks/binding/Binding.html#bind:A):

> Each time the value changes, in the current `@dom` method, all code after the current `bind` expression will be re-evaluated

As a result, the `calc.bind` call at [here](https://github.com/ccamel/playground-binding.scala/blob/ff89a1f/src/main/scala/com/ccm/me/playground/bindingscala/calc/ui.scala#L142) forces recreating the anchor element.

---

I created [a pull request](https://github.com/ccamel/playground-binding.scala/pull/1) to change the `class` attribute instead, by avoiding the `calc.bind` call before XHTML literals.